# Where can find complete example spagobi KPI

Tags: spagobi

Hi Please help me finding complete example on spagobi KPI or any tutorial would be great help.
I want to create KPI on daily revenue earned from my android AAP, any tutorial would be a great help to kick start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the the examples that get installed along with the All In One SpagoBI package

http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=204

Comment: I want video tutorial

Comment: Sure. Let me google that for you . There are quite a few videos https://m.youtube.com/results?q=spagobi%20kpi&sm=3